# Custom ValidationResult in model Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I should make Custom validation in the model, Its Work correctly but the validation message dose not shown and the field does not focused
Here is the Code

```
public class MyValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute//RequiredAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        CrossMove obj = (CrossMove)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var Ci_id_num = (string)value;
        string[] memberNames = new string[] { validationContext.MemberName };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Ci_id_num) && obj.Person_typ_cd == "7574")
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName) , memberNames);
        }
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Ci_id_num))
        {
            if(obj.Ci_id_num.Length < 9)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "رقم الهويه يتكون من 9 خانات";
                ErrorMessageResourceName = validationContext.MemberName;
                return new ValidationResult("رقم الهويه يتكون من 9 خانات", memberNames);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class CrossMove
{
    [MyValidator(ErrorMessage = "Length should be more than 9 diget")]
    public string Ci_id_num { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string Person_typ_cd { get; set; }
}
```

I use json on th Acction

```
return Json(new { status = response.StatusCode, transMsg = trans.ToList(), msg = response.Message, toastr = true, alert = true, close = 1 });
```

the ModelState become false if the length less than 9 but the felid dose not show message and dose not focused like other normal required

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input has-error">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Ci_id_num, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "Ci_id_num", placeholder = "رقم الهويه", type = "number"  })

                    <label for="Ci_id_num"> ابحث هنا</label>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ci_id_num, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Comment: If you want to see validation errors via `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` you should return `View(model)` in your controller, not Json(in case of validation failure).

Comment: Are you expecting cliengt side validation? For that you attribute needs to implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write the scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator` - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: I try to return view and dose not work.

Comment: I use json but other Fields validation work like that:

Comment: [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/2y5i3jhxs5n5v76/1.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy way to solve this issue 
I send array of fields that has an error

```
var erroneousFields = ModelState.Where(ms => ms.Value.Errors.Any())
                                    .Select(x => new { x.Key , x.Value.Errors });
```

Then I write a few javascript to display message and focus first field has error in the array

```
if (json.Keys.length > 0) {
                        $("#" + json.Keys[0].Key + "").focus();
                        console.log(json.Keys[0].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                        if (json.Keys[0].Errors[0].ErrorMessage.trim() != "")
                        {
                            //console.log(json.Keys[0].Errors.ErrorMessage);
                            ShowMssage("e: " + json.Keys[0].Errors[0].ErrorMessage.trim());
                        }
                    }
```